# Why is there a post-jQuery flash in Safari?

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, safari

I have a simple search box that it hidden until hover(over) and hides again on hover(out). In Firefox all is normal, but in Safari there is a tiny flash after the hide animation where the full bar is visible. You can see what is happening (in Safari only) on the homepage of my site: [stormink.net](http://stormink.net). (the search button is in the top-right corner)

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="searchForm"> <label id="searchButton" for="searchBox" value="Search"></label>
<input id="searchBox" type="text" value="Search...">
</form>
```

The CSS:

```
#searchForm { float: right; background-color: #333333 }
    #searchButton { 
        display: block; float: left; 
        height: 24px; width: 32px; 
        background: url(/images/STORMINKsprite.png) no-repeat;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-position: -325px 0;
        }
    #searchBox { 
        display: none; float: left;
        margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
        padding: 0 3px;
        border: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #ffffff;
        height: 15px;
        }
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchForm').hover(
    function(){
        $('#searchBox').show('slow');
    },
    function(){
        $('#searchBox').hide('slow');
    }
    );
});
```

Is there any way to get rid of this, or is it just standard jQuery? It would be quite distracting. Luckily its in Safari and not Firefox, but still not very fun...

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why that happens, but one thing that might help would be to take advantage of the second, optional callback funciton for the the hide function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#searchForm_trigger').hover(
    function(){
        $('#searchBox').css({display: "inherit"});
        $('#searchBox').show('slow');
    },
    function(){
        $('#searchBox').hide('slow', function() {
            $("#searchBox").css({display: "none"});
        });
    }
    );
});
```

You would have to modify your design slightly to do this, since it's all one object.  Put a fixed div named searchBox_trigger in the upper right (CSS: `position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0;`) and use this for the hover event.  Set its background to be the little search icon.

This *might* work, although you may have to play with it a little more to get it looking right.

By the way, I love the design.  Once you get some content in there it's going to be amazing.  You're really talented. :)  Do you do design for work, or just play?

Comment: Thanks so much for the compliment! That means a lot. I am currently a sophomore at design school, so I guess that would make me between play and work/play. 

For the jQuery, I'm slightly confused. First, the search icon is a label that is seperate from the search input box. (if that's what you mean by seperated) And second, what does setting the display on the box to inherit do in the beginning?

Comment: Ah cool, glad it's your design, then.  It looks phenomenal.

I didn't realize the icon was separate, in that case, you might not have a problem just using #searchBox for the hover.  The display: inherit causes the display attribute of the search field to return to whatever it would naturally be if you didn't set it in the CSS.  You can read more about the inherit value here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritvalue

Comment: Oh, but the display changes would have to be applied to the text box for the input only, not the icon, since you want that icon to stay visible.

Comment: By the way, do you have an e-mail address I could reach you at?  Got a question for you that I don't feel like asking on here.  Curse stackoverflow for not having private messaging, lol.